# Make a transparent 448*448 image

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

This is a simple challenge.

The task is to write code that outputs a 448*448 square image with 100% transparency.  The output should follow the [standard image rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9093/d).

Comment: What's to stop people from submitting a 0-byte answer which "outputs" a transparent (invisible) image to the screen?

Comment: @12Me21 Would that be 448*448?

Comment: Is this a parody of (or at least inspired by) a closed question on stackoverflow?

Comment: What's special about 448 px?

Comment: @dan04  CDXLVIII is the number of integer partitions of 33 into distinct parts.  It also  cannot be written as a sum of 3 squares.

Comment: @Foon  Definitely not a parody but certainly I was interested enough to ask on SO before realising it would be much more fun here.

Answer (score 28):

## Imagemagick in some shell, 35

```
convert -size 448x448 xc:none a.png
```

Is this allowed?

Comment: Oh! I had no idea this would work. It's surprising and clever, so yes!

Comment: Please specify the shell

Comment: Bash, I guess? That's what I used when I tested it. Any POSIX shell should work?

Comment: Works also in Windows (if ImageMagick is in the PATH before `\windows\system32`).

Comment: On Windows ImageMagick is not being shipped with `convert` tool, because the name clashes with system utility. You run `magick convert ... ` instead.

Comment: I believe since convert is the language you wish to use, you only need to calculate the parameters as part of the byte count, so only the `-size 448x448 xc:none a.png` part. This is from the rule that non-standard parameters count in the byte count - but the filename itself shouldn't

Comment: @SztupY the `convert` is part of ImageMagick, so calling it its own language would not work.

Comment: it's an own command. You can just say the language you are using is `ImageMagick Convert`. Might be worth opening a meta about it though

Answer (score 15):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Full program. Prints 448-by-448-by-4 array representing a 448-by-448 rgba image.

```apl
448 448 4⍴0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L@JiYUCGD/q3WIAEvqvAAYFAA)

`⍴` is **r**eshape

Comment: I don't know APL at all, but I guess it doesn't have a duplicate to golf the `448 448`?

Comment: 448*448=200704, so cant you replace the space separated 448 448 with 200704, saving 1 byte?

Comment: @NaCl In that case why not just multiply that by 4 and have `802832p0` as the answer?

Comment: @NaCl Because that's not one of the valid image formats [per default rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9104/43319).

Comment: @JohnHamilton For the same reason as [my answer to NaCl](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/181409/make-a-transparent-448448-image/181411?noredirect=1#comment437092_181411).

Comment: ironically that is how images are stored in most graphics image systems, as a one dimensional array

Answer (score 8):

## Go, 70

```
import i"image";func a()i.Image{return i.NewRGBA(i.Rect(0,0,448,448))}
```

Never seen a golf in Go before. Defines a function called a that outputs the image

Comment: Call it a Go-lf.

Answer (score 6):

## Java 8

**Saving the image to a file with path `s`, 101 bytes**

```
s->javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(new java.awt.image.BufferedImage(448,448,2),"png",new java.io.File(s))
```

[Try it online... somehow](https://tio.run/##XY4xa8MwEIV3/YrDkwSOhpKhYJohEEOGkiFj6XCxT845tmwkJQ4Y/3ZXTkKHDMcb7vser8YbruryMhcNeg/fyHYUbAM5gwVBPt46LsHIY3BsKzDckMWWVDi7bvCwuxfUB@5sNon@emq4AB8wxHh4bax7qT@/gK7yCt7NUeRgvma/2tRxy11zixVxp/dL7g96cBxIWhpg@WscwhPR26sx5Kh8gHK9/kyX@1Bp0tsqSf@N2JXH2dIrNWfCaCOTZ8GCqUxM0/wH)
**Returning the BufferedImage, 46 bytes**

```
v->new java.awt.image.BufferedImage(448,448,2)
```

**Saving the image to the file `f`, 83 bytes**

```
f->javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(new java.awt.image.BufferedImage(448,448,2),"png",f)
```

**Dumping PNG to STDOUT, 92 bytes (thanks ASCII-only!)**

```
v->javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(new java.awt.image.BufferedImage(448,448,2),"png",System.out)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY4xa8MwEIV3/YojkwSOhpChYNqh0ECGkiHQpXS42if3XFsy0tlOMf7trp1uHY5veN97XI0D7uvyeykaTAlekf2k2AtFhwXBaRoCl@D024bByFcMY4KXW0GdcPD5rLr@s@ECkqCsuOvtuqKvEtlX7x@AsUoG/jcndQL3uAz7p3p94Wa5xYo42PPG88WOkYW0pxG23OIof4p97p2jSOVd1MfjQ7bdwWS7zle77PqThFobejFLrpx12vdNY3I1z8sv)
Thanks to Kevin for saving a byte for the second and fourth solutions!

Comment: Do you mean empty or transparent?

Comment: I'm pretty sure empty pngs are transparent, are they not? I typed this up on my phone so I can't check

Comment: Just write to stdout

Comment: @ASCII-only So, write an empty (filled with zeros) 448*448*4 array to stdout? Anyways I like the idea of creating an actual PNG file.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart no i mean write the bytestream to stdout, you can just redirect in the stream anyway

Comment: [like this](https://tio.run/##XY4xa8MwFIR3/YpHJgkcDSFDwbRDIYEMIUPG0uHFfnKfE0tGeo5TjH@7Y6dbh@OG@467Gu@4rsvrVNwwJTgi@0GxF4oOC4L9cA9cgtNGfmLoE@weBbXCweejarvLjQtIgjLbC2zmvj5LZF99fQPGKhn43xzUHtz7pM36o57XH5YbrIiDPSx@ONk@spD21MOSW@zlD7GfnXMUqXyBert9yxZtTLZqfbXKzr9JqLGhEzPlytn5da7GcXoC). also you could use `bash` on TIO to verify your existing solution works

Comment: @ASCII-only I didn't know ImageIO.write accepted streams. Guess it makes sense

Comment: You can golf the `()->` in two of your answers to `v->`, since it's allowed to have [an empty unused input](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12681/are-we-allowed-to-use-empty-input-we-wont-use-when-no-input-is-asked-regarding) (for which I personally use `Void`). Your last TIO would then be [this instead](https://tio.run/##XY4xa8MwEIV3/YojkwSOhpChYNqh0ECGkiHQpXS42if3XFsy0tlOMf7trp1uHY5veN97XI0D7uvyeykaTAlekf2k2AtFhwXBaRoCl@D024bByFcMY4KXW0GdcPD5rLr@s@ECkqCsuOvtuqKvEtlX7x@AsUoG/jcndQL3uAz7p3p94Wa5xYo42PPG88WOkYW0pxG23OIof4p97p2jSOVd1MfjQ7bdwWS7zle77PqThFobejFLrpx12vdNY3I1z8sv).

Comment: what about [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY4xD4IwEIX3/ooby2AnBxLUxMHRCTfDUKHgYWmb9ioS42/HEnUyL3mXu5d873p5l6u@uc04OOsJ@rSLSKjF3ns5hYL9BW00NaE1oozOaVS@YKzWMgQ4SjRP5uJFYw2BJKVxt9jAkAJekkfTnSuQvgsZ0NXbMcDhUSu34J7sx9ugoXO1aAftdubZamfUCMt1nefV16q5YOUUSA3CRhIuwUkbDp@/RaOUO9lPJ4dWdIp4BkkFe73mNw) output as 3d array rows, cols, rgba. like Python answer

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul because I want to output an actual image and not a pixel by pixel representation of one

Comment: Thank you for outputting an actual image!

Comment: @Anush you're welcome

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
448ṁ4¬¥þ
```

A niladic Link which yields a 448 by 448 RGBA array of transparent black pixels.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/ExOLhzkaTQ2sOLT287/9/AA)**

#### How?

```
448ṁ4¬¥þ - Link: no arguments
448      - 448
       þ - outer-product with: -- i.e. [[f(x,y) for y in [1..448]] for x in [1..448]]
      ¥  -   last two links as a dyad:
   ṁ4    -     mould like [1,2,3,4]  -- e.g. x=7 -> [7,7,7,7]
     ¬   -     logical NOT                       -> [0,0,0,0]
```

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>74</s> 69 bytes

```js
f=
(_=document.createElement`canvas`)=>_.toDataURL(_.height=_.width=448)
;document.write(f());
```

Returns a PNG image encoded as a data: URL suitable e.g. for setting as the `src` of an `HTMLImageElement`. Edit: Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Shaggy and a further 2 bytes thanks to @Arnauld.

Comment: [71 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcqhDoAgEADQfyFBkESwYNJmcjPfbnATnILDUz8fNb7trXjj6Uo8uEnZU60SrM/u2imxdoWQadjolxQO05eFUrYDzblHxnkaJehAcQlsQT/Rc7DGtKrWFw)?

Comment: `document.createElement\`canvas\` ` should work, saving 2 more bytes.

Comment: If createelement is valid would seeing document.body and using the fact an id becomes a variable be valid? Also stack snippet pls

Comment: Could you add something like `d=document` at the top and replace `document` with `d`? Should save ~5 characters.

Comment: @Luke The `document.write` is just part of the stack snippet, not part of the function, so it doesn't count anyway.

Answer (score 6):

## Java 8, 23 (or 20) bytes

```java
v->new int[448][448][4]
```

Returns a 3D array of 448x448x4 0s.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LU5LCoMwEN17ilkmC7NyUZAWeoC6sXRTXKQxldg4Sn5FimdP44eBBzPvM6/nged9@4lCc2vhxhX@MgCFTpo3FxKqdd0Oz2YdEOQxqhYCLROxZAms404JqADhDDHkF5TfzVAUp@aAJpardPIvnaSHI6xBQ3pJamcUdimdm87S/WU9WycHNnrHpsQ6jaRPbZl3SrOrMXy2rJVyuo@7myATBL3WlB7dlvgH)

**Explanation:**

```java
v->  // Method with empty unused parameter and 3D integer-array as return-type
  new int[448][448][4]
     // Create a 3D array of dimensions 448 by 448 by 4 (filled with 0s by default)
```

---

```java
v->new int[448][448]
```

Returns a 448x448 matrix of 0s.

In Java, RGBA values can be [represented by an integer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_INT_ARGB). The hexadecimal `0x00000000` would represent `00` for red, green, blue, and alpha respectively. And `0x00000000` is equal to the integer `0`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY47DoMwEER7TrGlXeCKIhJKpBwgNInSIArHOMjELMi/CEWc3TGfZqWdfTszPQ8879tPFJpbCzeu8JcBKHTSvLmQUK3rJtRN3YAgz1G1EGiZ5CVLwzrulIAKEM4QQ35B@d3wojg124jlyk3@pRN34GF1GVIauTujsEvW3HSW7mn32To5sNE7NqWr00j6VJR5pzS7GsNny1opp8e4fxNkgqDXmtKj2BL/)

Comment: Ah ah ah, love it :-) Doesn't it work with simply `v->new int[448][448]`? Because a color can be represented with an integer (RGBA) in Java.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire No, I need the four 0s per 448x448 pixel for the RBGA values. EDIT: Hmm.. is an integer `0-255` a valid RBGA value? I know it's a valid RGB value, but also RGBA? I almost never use images in Java, so not too familiar with them. I simply based my 4 inner 0s on other answers.

Comment: Yes, four 0s as (in hexadecimal) `0x00000000` that fit on an int. The first 2 hex digits are the Alpha, the next 2 are the red, the next 2 are the green, the final 2 are the blue.So you only need an integer. See [BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_INT_ARGB). You have 4 values, summarized as one integer. And `0x00000000` is equal to `0`.

Comment: I think this is the first time in ~2 years here I've seen Java actually be competitive!

Comment: @Shaggy With these golfing languages around it's still not that competitive.. Besides, I had a few other semi-competitive Java answers in the past, like [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113448/is-this-even-or-odd/113451#113451), or [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167239/52210) that was winning until the Bash showed up (and R golfed its answer).

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9vc2FiaWX//zTDhTDCuDQ4OMKp0LjCuMKu0Lj//w), <s>12</s> <s>10</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
448LDδ4Å0
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fxMTCx@XcFpPDrQb//wMA)

or alternatively:

```
¾4Ž1ÂDиии
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0D6To3sNDze5XNgBgv//AwA)

-2 bytes thanks to *@Emigna*.
-1 byte thanks to *@Adnan*.

Outputs a 448x448x4 3D list of 0s.

**Explanation:**

```python
448LD      # Push a list in the range [1,448], and duplicate it
     δ     # Outer product; apply the following double-vectorized:
      4Å0  #  Push a list of 4 0s: [0,0,0,0]
           # (and output the result implicitly)

  Ž1ÂD     # Push compressed integer 448, and duplicate it
      и    # Create a list of 448 times 448
 4     и   # Transform it into a list of 448 times 448 times 4
¾       и  # Transform it into a list of 448 times 448 times 4 times 0
           # (and output the result implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E answer of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `Ž1Â` is `448`.

Answer (score 5):

## Processing, 66 bytes

```java
PGraphics g=createGraphics(448,448);g.beginDraw();g.save("a.png");
```

Answer (score 5):

## [dzaima/APL + APLP5](https://github.com/dzaima/APL#processing-integration), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
{P5.img⍴∘0,⍨448}
```

Function that outputs an image object that can be drawn to the screen (for no effect) or converted back to pixel values.

-2 thanks to [ngn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24908/ngn)!

Comment: would this work? `{P5.img⍴∘0,⍨448}`

Comment: @ngn it indeed would, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2.7, 17 Bytes (22 With Print)

```
[[[0]*4]*488]*488
```

With Print:

```
print[[[0]*4]*488]*488
```

As variable:

```
x=[[[0]*4]*488]*488
```

As an array of RGBA is allowed, that is what I have created above, defaulting to all 0's - meaning black, but totally transparent.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM68kOjraIFbLBIgsLMDE//8A)

Comment: Again, with this one, just multiply manually and you get `[0]*802816` that should also work.

Comment: @JohnHamilton Correct me if I'm wrong, but I do believe that it would have to be a 3D array (An array of rows of pixels) i.e. array[pixel x coord][pixel y coord][r/g/b/a]

Comment: Not quite as concise but here is an alternative that gets the zeros into a numpy array... np.zeros([4]+[448]*2)

Answer (score 5):

## HTML, 25 bytes

Is this valid?

```
<svg height=448 width=448
```

[Test it](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VRrQPY) (`background` applied with CSS so you can "see" it)

Comment: I don't believe that this is valid, as writting `<svg height=448 width=448` into an html file and opening it produces an empty `<body>`. **However**, with the penality of 1 byte, if you write `<svg height=448 width=448>`, it produces a `<body>` with an empty SVG image.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, we define languages by their interpreter rather than their (intended) implementation. That an interpreter exists (in this case CodePen) that allows us to omit the closing `>` means that this is, indeed, valid, as far as the markup goes.

Comment: Codepen adds additional HTML code to make it work. It adds a `<!DOCTYPE html>`, `<html>`, `<head>`, `<style>`, `<script>` and everything goes to the `<body>`. Some of the additional code is required to produce the desired output. You can see that the resulting code is parsed as `<svg height="448" width="448" < body></svg>`, because it writes `<svg height=448 width=448 </body>` in the iframe. As such, I still believe it isn't valid.

Answer (score 5):

## Rust - <s>206</s> <s>201</s> 168 bytes

```
use std::{io::Write,fs::File};fn main(){let mut v=vec![0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,192,1,192,1,32,0];v.extend(vec![0u8;802816]);File::create("o.tga").unwrap().write(&v);}
```

This writes an actual, readable o.tga file, without any libraries or builtin functions, using the TGA binary format per http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/tga/ , by hard coding the width and height into the binary file header.

---

-5 bytes shorten filename, fix img size, @ASCII-only

Comment: does it need to be printed to a file though :P

Comment: does it even need to be 2 dimensional? I could just say [0;444*444*4]; and say i created a 444x444 transparent image. im making it interesting.

Comment: well also `a` would work as file name would it not. btw it's 448*448 not 444*444 so this is invalid

Comment: oops, ha ha thanks

Comment: to make it even more interesting, run length encode it :P (image data should be `[255,0,0,0,0]` 6272 times (`[0,0,0,0]` 128 times, repeated 6272 times). image type would then be `10` not `2`. even better, colormap for shorter run length encoding (`0,0,0,0` -> `0`)

Comment: i think that would take more space than my version.

Comment: of course, but you said you wanted to make it interesting :P (rle colormapped should be something like `[0,1,9,0,0,1,0,32,0,0,0,0,192,1,192,1,32,0,0,0,0,0]` and `[255,0]` 6272 times btw). also, i wonder if you could make the first one a string? (escaping things like `0` -> `\0` and/or `2` -> `\x02` if you need to)

Comment: i couldnt figure out how the string version would be shorter.

Comment: You could make every value 1 byte, with no delimiter ad well, of course this assumes 0x00 is valid in a rust file and that strings have `iter`

Comment: i am not aware of how to do it at the current moment. rust strings are like, literally, utf8. ill try some things though

Comment: the problem with string encoding is that its not easily convertible to bytes, any way i can figure to do it will take up more space than just having the vector of bytes separated by commas.

Comment: You could save quite a lot if you sent it to the standard output: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/fn.stdout.html and it is acceptable (most upvoted as well, in the meta): https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9095

Comment: "When operating in a console, the Windows implementation of this stream does not support non-UTF-8 byte sequences. Attempting to write bytes that are not valid UTF-8 will return an error." - i wanted it to be portable

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 21 bytes

```cs
_=>new int[448,448,4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcixCsMgEADQvV/hqOQKGRwKpxn7Cx2CFCoKd4KBxNCh@O3WBAod3vL8dvUbtfuevVleHHwBymUGcJOItj3tlMNbHKX1DU6u4SUuq@wpyI5IpjfSMKjPr7k3n83/nXqLZDSmYx8rlSCjHNVMwJCcwlpr@wI)

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 48 bytes

```cs
_=>(Enumerable.Repeat((0,0,0,0),200704),448,448)
```

Apparently outputting `[1D array of pixels, width, height]` is ok, so this outputs a tuple of `(IEnumerable of pixels, width, height).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcxBC4JAEAXge7@i40xusopQsCp0MBA6dekYuowwi66h6yn67ZsKYQwPHh@P0eNRj@yvk9VpXxvSTkBZ2KmjoapbSoGtE3/BfGtNlvtnlsM2D@/0osoBSLEeiljKk0xQJMl5CXq1a/ph@brnTCpOZ1QcBPj@sZnZrGxmfgzsCBqIMSwddVFYtNSRdRcHfIhkYBDVurmxJUD18V8)

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 58 bytes

```cs
_=>Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Repeat((0,0,0,0),448),448)
```

The original matrix returning answer.

Since the image IO rules allow output as a matrix of RGB values, this submission outputs a matrix of RGBA values, represented by tuples with four values, all being 0.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5@UlZpcouPpmleam1qUmJSTaoPM1sjMK9FBwpp2dnZptnb/423tEKr0glILUhNLNDBFNAx0wFBTx8TEAkL8t@ZKyy9KTUzO0ChLLFJIVMjMU0jTMNTUrEYRzwSJJ2pyhRdllqRqZGorKShpWoM5Ppl5qRqa1ly1/wE)

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 192 bytes

Sadly, PHP kinda sucks in that aspect because it requires a whole lot of code. But then again, where doesn't PHP suck.

```
$i=imagecreatetruecolor(448,448);imagesavealpha($i,true);$b=imagecolorallocatealpha($i,0,0,0,127);imagefill($i,0,0,$b);imagepng($i,'i.png');header('Content-type: image/png');readfile('i.png');
```

Ungolfed:

```
$i=imagecreatetruecolor(448,448);         // Create a new image with a set width
imagesavealpha($i,true);                  // Tell PHP to save alphachannels on that image
$b=imagecolorallocatealpha($i,0,0,0,127); // set the actual transparency values
imagefill($i,0,0,$b);                     // Fill the image with the color saved above
imagepng($i,'i.png');                     // Save the file as PNG
header('Content-type: image/png');        // Set the content type for the browser
readfile('i.png');                        // Read the file and output it
```

Obviously, if you just want to create it without outputting it, you can omit the `header()` and `readfile()` commands. Still, it's idiotically long.

Comment: on the positive side, this is one of the most 'readable' answers that indicates exactly what its doing

Comment: @donbright Not really the point of codegolfing tho. ;P However, there is no other way to do this in PHP I guess, unless I just echo some HTML.

Comment: @YUNOWORK According to the rules, you can export an array. You can use `'<?php return '.var_export(array_fill(0,952576,0),1).';';` to export the array in an executable way. you can do `php -f image.php > array.php`, and somewhere else you can do `$array = include('array.php');` to have an usable array again. But I don't know if it is valid, so, I'm giving it to you to add as an alternative. Or even a `<?=json_encode(array_fill(0,952576,0));`.

Comment: By the way, `true` can be replaced with `1`, to save 3 bytes. Reading the documentation of `imagepng()`, you can just do `header('Content-type: image/png');imagepng($i);`. I believe you can also replace `$b=imagecolorallocatealpha($i,0,0,0,127);imagefill($i,0,0,$b);` with `imagefill($i,0,0,imagecolorallocatealpha($i,0,0,0,127));` but dont quote me on that.

Comment: I just tested and `<? imagecolorallocatealpha($i=imagecreate(448,448),0,0,0,127);header('Content-type: image/png');imagepng($i);` produces a transparent image (109 bytes). Automatically sends the image to the browser/standard output and everything.

Answer (score 4):

**Python 3.7 - PIL Imported, 30 bytes**

```
Image.new("LA",[448]*2).show()
```

This requires an import but has the benefit of creating and displaying an actual image file rather than an abstract empty array.

Explanation:

```
from PIL import Image
Image.new(    // create a new image
mode="LA"     // select LA colour mode, this is grey-scale plus an alpha channel
size=[448]*2  // size argument needs to be a 2D tuple, [448*2] is a better golf shot than (448,448)
color=0       // populates the image with the specified colour, helpfully preset to transparent
).show()      // display the image object
```

Image.show() will open the image in your default image program. In my case this opens a temporary bitmap file in Windows Photo Viewer but results may vary. Arguably this is cheating since the bitmap representation contains no transparency

Variations...

```
Image.new("LA",[448]*2)                 // 24 bytes but doesn't open image
Image.new("LA",[448]*2).show()          // 30 bytes, shows you a bitmap
Image.new("LA",[448]*2).save("x.png")   // 37 bytes, saves image to disk
```

Comment: If you do not count your import, you should state your language as _Python 3.7 -- PIL imported_ or something similar. Furthermore, in your explanation you capitalize `Import`.

Comment: Thanks, corrected. Should I give my answer as 24 bytes, 30 or 37?

Comment: The byte count depends on the language you use. As of now, your submission takes 30 bytes in the language _Python 3 with PIL imported_. If you wrote in _Python 3_, it would most likely be longer. Of course, if you use the language _Python 3 with the entire PIL namespace imported_, your answer would be `new("LA",[448]*2).show()`, 26 bytes.

Comment: Thanks so much for submitting code I can actually run and which produces output I can test!

Answer (score 4):

## MATLAB, 31 bytes

```
imwrite(nan(448),'.png','tr',1)
```

Creates a 448 x 448 matrix of `NaN` values, and then uses `imwrite` to save them to a PNG file named `'.png'` and sets the transparency to 1, making it transparent. The [`'Transparency'` parameter name](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html#btv3cny-1-Transparency) is able to be abbreviated to `'tr'` as MATLAB allows for partial string  matching of parameter names as long as the shortened version is unique among available parameters.

Comment: wait, why 443??

Comment: @ASCII-only Fat fingers :)

Comment: O_o that was an insanely quick reply

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
x4Wẋ448Ɗ⁺
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/CJPzhrm4TE4tjXY8ad/3/DwA)

Outputs a 448x448x4 array

Thanks to @JonathanAllan for saving a byte.

Comment: `2¡` can be `⁺`

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 39 bytes

```javascript
_=>[w=448,w,Array(w*w).fill([0,0,0,0])]
```

Apparently outputting `[height, width, 1d array of RGBA values]` is ok.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1i663NbExEKnXMexqCixUqNcq1xTLy0zJ0cj2kAHDGM1Y/9bcyXn5xXn56Tq5eSna6RpaGr@BwA)

-3 bytes thanks to @Arnauld

Comment: invalid... it's a list of strings

Comment: Also you can output `[1D array of pixels, width, height]`

Comment: @ASCII-only Fixed now

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1i7asagosVJDo9zWxMRCU6tcUy8tMydHI9pABwxjNXXKdcpj/1tzJefnFefnpOrl5KdrpGloav4HAA) or [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1i663NbExEKnXMexqCixUqNcq1xTLy0zJ0cj2kAHDGM1Y/9bcyXn5xXn56Tq5eSna6RpaGr@BwA) if we can output `[width, height, array]`.

Answer (score 3):

## SmileBASIC, 27 bytes

```
DIM A[448,448]SAVE"DAT:I",A
```

Saves a 2-dimensional 448x448 array filled with 0s to a file named `DAT:I` (Which is shorter than defining a function that returns the array, somehow)

The standard formats (used by all graphics functions) for colors in SmileBASIC are 32 bit ARGB and 16 bit 5551 RGBA, and `0` is transparent in both of them.

Comment: What makes this transparent instead of black?

Comment: The colors are in 4 byte `ARGB` format (commonly used in Smilebasic), so `0x00000000` is Alpha = 0, Red = 0, Green = 0, Blue = 0. Black would be `0xFF000000`.

Comment: kudos to SmileBasic for using a RAW image format lol

Comment: I would complain on technicality that this isn't an image format since it isn't `GRP` but I'll let it go since the actual data being stored is the same.

Comment: @snail_ It's just outputting a matrix of pixels, not using a specific image format.

Comment: @12Me21 It's valid according to PPCG

Comment: raw pixel data is sometimes referred to as a raw image format, and a lot of cameras provide a raw pixel buffer data file. Photoshop can even read certain types of raw image formats. Unity3d can also use it for heightmaps

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 33 bytes

```
a: make image![448x448 0.0.0.255]
```

Opacity defaults to fully opaque(0)

This is how to use it /a full program/ :

```
Red [ ]
a: make image! [ 448x448 0.0.0.255 ]
view [ image a ]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 10 bytes

```
º4♦7*_ß{.a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///QLpNHM5eZa8Ufnl@tl/j/PwA)

### Explanation

```
º            push [0]
 4           push 4
  ♦7*        push 64*7=448
     _       duplicate TOS
      ß      wrap last three elements in array (stack is now [[0], [4, 448, 448]])
       {     foreach in [4, 448, 448]
        .    repeat TOS x times
         a   wrap TOS in array
```

This method saves 1 byte compared to the "standard" `♦7*_4º*a*a*`

Answer (score 3):

## [ScPL for iOS Shortcuts](https://scpl.dev), 98 bytes

```
Text"R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
Base64Encode Decode
ResizeImage 448
```

[image: Screenshot]

[Shortcut iCloud Link](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/a010eff12cab4f4c94a15f8d4bc6109c)

Takes a 1x1 transparent gif encoded as base64 and resizes it

Comment: that was ... weird... what is the icloud link i just went to? ?

Comment: @donbright when you share a shortcut from the shortcuts app, it makes that link

Answer (score 2):

## [Jstx](https://github.com/Quantum64/Jstx), 24 [bytes](https://quantum64.github.io/Jstx/codepage)

```
♪☺ü@/øP♦£Q)%)£Q◄úæD)%)£Q
```

Explanation

```
♪☺ü@ # Push literal 448
/    # Store the first stack value in the a register.
ø    # Push literal 0
P    # Push four copies of the first stack value.
♦    # Push literal 4
£Q   # Push stack values into a list of the size of the first stack value starting with the second stack value.
)    # Push the value contained in the a register.
%    # Push the second stack value the absolute value of the first stack value times.
)    # Push the value contained in the a register.
£Q   # Push stack values into a list of the size of the first stack value starting with the second stack value.
◄úæ  # Push literal \n
D    # Push the sum of the second and first stack values.
)    # Push the value contained in the a register.
%    # Push the second stack value the absolute value of the first stack value times.
)    # Push the value contained in the a register.
£Q   # Push stack values into a list of the size of the first stack value starting with the second stack value.
```

[Try it online!](https://quantum64.github.io/Jstx/JstxGWT-1.0.3/JstxGWT.html?code=4pmq4pi6w7xAL8O4UOKZpsKjUSklKcKjUeKXhMO6w6ZEKSUpwqNR)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 21 bytes

```r
array(0,c(448,448,4))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P7GoKLFSw0AnWcPExEIHjDU1//8HAA)

Returns a 3D-array of zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 bytes

```
448ÆZç4Æ0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/38TE4nBb1OHlJofbDP7/1w0EAA)

Answer (score 2):

### C++, SFML, 131 bytes

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
void f(){sf::Image i;i.create(448,448);i.createMaskFromColor(sf::Color::Black);i.saveToFile("a.png");}
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript + HTML, 56 bytes

```js
location=C.toDataURL()
```

```html
<canvas id=C width=448 height=448>
```

Clicking "Run code snippet" will generate a 448x448 transparent PNG in an IFRAME. You may then right-click "Save image as..." to download it to your computer.